# Use tf.image.random_flip_left_right method to batch of images

Tags: tensorflow

Does any way to use **tf.image.random_flip_left_right** method for batch of images?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's always annoying when these kinds of functions don't support batches. Use `tf.map_fn` to map the batch onto the function. Though note that this breaks your problem into many small operations which aren't as efficient on the GPU as they could be if `random_flip_left_right` supported batch operations.

```
imgs = tf.map_fn(tf.image.random_flip_left_right, imgs_4d_tensor)
```